# How do I trigger runat="server" without having access to add this code to the HTML button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am adding a Google reCAPTCHA to a form, but doing it through a CMS system (Luminate Online- which is awful). I have no access to edit the HTML button code, so I am unable to add the code runat="server" into the button, so the form does not validate. Is there another way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<head runat="server">

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_action() {
        var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        console.log("Resp" + v);
        if (v == '') {
            document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML = "You can't leave 
Captcha Code empty";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML = "Captcha 
completed";
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML: (I can add HTML through a caption in the CMS, but am just unable to edit the button directly)

```
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-
  sitekey="SITEKEYHERE"></div>
```

Basically, I have this working on a test page when I put runat="server" into the submit button. However, I need to get this working through the CMS and I am unable to edit the submit button. So, right now, anyone can submit the form without checking the reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

`runat="server"` is not a standard HTML attribute. It only applies to certain ASP.NET systems.

If your CMS does not support reCaptcha, you're out of luck. There's no way to add that support through HTML alone.

Comment: Well the test page I did was in the CMS and it functioned properly. I think the CMS does support reCAPTCHA.
The issue is that I need to add the reCAPTCHA to the survey builder in the CMS (the test page was done on a pagebuilder page which is just a blank page). Hopefully that makes sense?